# How to always rewrite author archive page URL even if the author does not have a post

Tags: urls, rewrite-rules

My understanding about author archive page URL rewriting is that as long as the author has atleast one post/page the URL for the archive page ofthe author will be re-written to:

```
http://mysite.com/author/%authorname%
```

However, if the author does not have any post/page then the URL for the archive page will be of the form

```
http://mysite.com/?author=id
```

How can we force wordpress to always rewrite the URL to /author-base/%author% even if the author does not possess any post/page.

Comment: If author does not posses any posts then what will actually be displayed on the page? I mean you can always show the authors with no posts by `<?php wp_list_authors('hide_empty=0'); ?>` but redirecting to an author archive page that is empty seems useless.

Comment: @Borek Why that? You could show pretty much all info entered in the (possibly extended) profile page like "Bio", contact methods, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We managed this by hijacking the default author template and setting up our own.

Set up a new url rewrite for team members:

```
add_action('init', function () {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'team';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base. '/%author%';
});
```

In the template we then use:

```
$uid = get_query_var('author');
```

to get the user's id.

From there you can build out your own template (author.php) for your authors.

We approached this from the perspective of wanting a custom template and url structure for our authors, but ended up solving your problem in the process (I think).